# iPhone certificate and provisioning...etc on new mac machine?

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning, keychain, deploying

I had an older mac mini that I had used to register the certifications and....etc.
I never really got to the stage for actually using them since i only tested on the iPhone simulator.

Today I have a new mac mini, and i am trying to deploy to a device.
Is there any gotchas here that im missing with this new mac mini?

When i Build & Go to device 3.0 i get an error.
"Code sign error: the identity "iPhone Developer: " doesnt match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain".

And indeed, when i go to the key access chain app, i can see that my keys dont have the certificate associated with it (even thought I have the certificate "iPhone Developer: " listed.

Any insights into this entirely to complex of a process would help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

There's a new feature in X-Code 3.2 and later that makes this a great deal easier.

1. On your old computer, in X-code, go to the Organizer window.
2. Click "Developer Profile" on the left pane. Then click "Export Developer Profile" on the right pane.
3. Save the file and transfer it to your new computer.
4. On your new computer, in X-Code, go to the Organizer window.
5. Click "Developer Profile" on the left pane, then click "Import Developer Profile" on the right pane.
6. Choose the file, and all should work well. At least, it worked for me.

I think this transfers the private key, sets up the public key and necessary certificates. I don't know if it helps with distribution credentials.

Comment: I had to export/import my certificates from/to the Keychain Access app first.  Only then would importing my Provisioning Profiles work (i.e. sync with the correct certificates)